# How to render class selector stored as a string in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Component.ts file with selector stored as a string in testWidget variable

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss'],
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }
    dashboard: any;
    ngOnInit(): void {}
    
    // variable with a child component selector stored as a string
    testWidget = `<app-dashboard></app-dashboard>`;
}
```

In html file this should render the component.

```
  <testWidget></testWidget>
```

Any other approach that dynamically renders the component will also work as selector names will come from the database

Comment: You can't have Angular dynamically render HTML strings. This is the recommended approach to dynamically load components: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Issue is I will have over 400+ components and I am looking for a way to not write that down one by one

Comment: You don't have to, do you? You just need a reference to your component class, just like you'd need to have a string reference to the name of your component. Then you can have it dynamically rendered